# How to run adonis command in ace command file

Tags: node.js, backend, adonis.js

```
const { Command } = require('@adonisjs/ace')
const util = require('util')
const execSync = util.promisify(require('child_process').execSync)

const defaultSeedOrder = []

class SeedSync extends Command {
  static get signature () {
    return `seed:sync
    {
      order? : Comma separated of seeds
    }`
  }

  static get description () {
    return 'Seeds based on a list instead of running all seeds async.'
  }

  handle (args, options) {
    let seedOrder;

    if (args.order !== null) {
      seedOrder = args.order.split(/=(.+)/)[1].split(',')
    } else {
      seedOrder = defaultSeedOrder
    }

    for (const seed of seedOrder) {
      console.log(seed)
      execSync(`adonis seed --files='${seed}'`, (e, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (!stdout.includes('Seeded database in')) {
          this.error(`${this.icon('error')} Error: `)
        }

        console.log(stdout)
      })
    }
  }
}

module.exports = SeedSync
```

> I want an ace command to run seed sequentially, I have copied this code from here:[Link to the original code](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/issues/838)
>
> But it doesnt seem to work at all for me. 
>   [image: I just get this when I run it]
>
> Any help will be much appreciated, Thank you

Comment: can you put ```'App/Commands/SeedSync'``` in ```start/app.js``` **commands** array ?

Comment: check this https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/ace

Comment: I did both already

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with these 2 blocks.

This signature needs to be like this to work and get the order variable correctly:

```
static get signature () {
    return `
    seed:sync
    { --order=@value: Run only selected files }
    `
  }
```

AND

```js
const exec = execSync(`adonis seed --files='${seed}' --force`, {stdio: 'inherit'})
```

Remove the commas on `--files='${seed}'` so that it reads `--files=${seed}`

Because on the terminal, we call the command using `adonis seed:sync --order=''` (this single comma is passed to adonis Seed.js and causes the error "Nothing to Seed")

Comment: add necessary tags and title